# Django - Shorten text content retrieved in html template

Tags: html, django

I would like to know how to shorten text content retrieved to get a preview instead of getting a block of text in the html template

From: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

To:

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa....

The code that is used to retrieve the contents is :

```
   <a class="list_content" href="/qna/view" onclick="document.forms['q_title_{{ q.id }}'].submit(); return false" title="{{ q.content }}">{{ q.content }} </a><br/>
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that "q.content" is a string you could use the [slice](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/templates/builtins/#slice) command:

```
{{ q.content|slice:":255" }}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Django 1.4, [truncatechars](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatechars) filter will be the best way to go:

```
{{ q.content|truncatechars:25 }}
```

Answer (score 1):

[truncatechars](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatechars) template filter for django 1.4